# How do I style an article inside a div?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How do I style an article inside a div?

The border now spans the full width of a 3 column div, but I would like for each of the three articles to have a seperate border.

I tried this but no luck.

```
#bloghomesection article {
    border-radius: .3125em;
    border: 0 solid #D8D8D8;
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
    min-height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: can you show your html code

Comment: add your html and create a snippet please

Comment: what you have exactly do share more detail

Comment: I can't the code is way too long.

Comment: http://kozio.website-id.nl/ is the website, just below the slider are the blog posts.

Comment: I can't see a problem with that, I did a [doodle](https://codepen.io/DeeLiciouz/pen/JardjY) and it works just fine. Please add the html of the `<div>` with the `<article>`s. It can be slimmed down to a minimum.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

Try styling your CSS with this:-

```
.fusion-posts-container > article
```

So your CSS will look something like:-

```
.fusion-posts-container > article {
    border-radius: .3125em;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #D8D8D8;
    min-height: 400px;
}
```

This will target each individual article.

Thanks,
Scott